# Masking nan values from an xarray dataset for scikit.learn mulltiple linear regression following scipy

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, python-xarray

I'm attempting to use scikit-learn.linear_model's LinearRegression find the multiple linear regression coefficients for different variables at each latitude and longitude point along the time dimension like so:

```
for i in range(len(data.lat)):
    for j in range(len(data.lon)):
         storage_dframe[i, j, :] = LinearRegression().fit(np.array((data.ivar1.values[:, i, j].reshape(-1, 1),
                                                                    data.ivar2.values[:, i, j].reshape(-1, 1)).reshape(len(data.time), 2),
                                                          data.dvar.values[:, i, j].reshape(len(data.time)).coef_)
```

While this general form works, there are abundant NaN values in my data because it comes from real observations. I generally do not want to impute data whenever possible, trying to preserve whatever real relations there might be. Is it possible to copy a behavior from [scipy.stats.linregress](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html), where "Missing values are considered pair-wise: if a value is missing in x, the corresponding value in y is masked?" This feels like the best route; otherwise, could I add a conditional clause along the lines of

```
if data.ivar1[:, i, j].isnull() or data.ivar[:, i, j].isnull() == True:
     storage_dfram[i, j, :] = np.nan
else:
     storage_dframe[i, j, :] = LinearRegression().fit(np.array((data.ivar1.values[:, i, j].reshape(-1, 1),
                                                                data.ivar2.values[:, i, j].reshape(-1, 1)).reshape(len(data.time), 2),
                                                      data.dvar.values[:, i, j].reshape(len(data.time)).coef_)
```

I've attempted essentially that, with no success. Please feel free to chime in!

Comment: I'm a little confused by what the SciPy docs mean about scipy.stats.linregress, because it definitely doesn't tolerate NaN. If you put in NaN, then every field in the result is NaN. There's also no code to detect missing values. This might be something left over from a previous version of the code.

Comment: Regardless of that, NumPy has a way to drop values by a boolean, so you could do something like `missing = np.nan(x) | np.nan(y); x = x[~missing]; y = y[~missing]`, where x and y are the input arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This boolean clause handles it:

```
if data.isel(lat=i,lon=j).ivar1.isnull().any() or data.isel(lev=2,lat=i,lon=j).ivar2.isnull().any() or data.isel(lev=2, lat=i,lon=j).ivar3.isnull().any() or data.isel(lev=0, lat=i,lon=j).ivar4.isnull().any() or data2.isel(lat=i, lon=j).dvar.isnull().any() == True:
     storage_dframe[i, j, :] = np.nan
else:
     storage_dframe[i, j, :] = LinearRegression(...)
```

where ivarx is the xth independent variable and dvar is the dependent variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is difficult to read, especially without context, so here's a simpler example of what I think you're trying to do:

```py
# generate some fake input and output data
inp = np.array(range(10))
# inp -> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

outp = np.array([x*x if x%2 else np.nan for x in inp])
# outp -> [nan,  1., nan,  9., nan, 25., nan, 49., nan, 81.]

mask = ~np.isnan(outp)
# mask -> [False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True]

masked_inp = inp[mask]
# masked_inp -> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

masked_outp = outp[mask]
# masked_outp -> [ 1.,  9., 25., 49., 81.]
```